# Searching for specific text in python

Tags: python, regex, search, f5, netmiko

hopefully this is a quick an easy on!
I am trying to do a search for a hostname on a device and then use that hostname to dictate the config that is sent to it via netmiko.
I think I'm failing because the output is not on one line.
As a test at the moment I am just trying to print the output as follows:

```
device_name = net_connect.send_command('show running-config sys global-settings hostname')
hostname = re.search('^hostname', device_name, re.M)
print(hostname)
```

When I run the above command on the device manually the output is like this:

```
sys global-settings {

    hostname triton.lakes.hostname.net

}
```

So do I need to adjust the re.search to take into account the seperate lines to just capture the 'hostname triton.lakes.hostname.net' line?

Many thanks

Comment: `^` won't match because `hostname` is indented (i.e the line starts with white-space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[re](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)

`(?=...)`

> Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

`(?<=...)`

> Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for ... that ends at the current position. This is called a positive lookbehind assertion. (?<=abc)def will find a match in 'abcdef', since the lookbehind will back up 3 characters and check if the contained pattern matches.

Demo:
`(?<={).*(?=})`

> It means to match strings beginning with `{` and ending with `}`

```py
import re

s = """
sys global-settings {

    hostname triton.lakes.hostname.net

}
"""

print(re.search(r"(?<={)\s+(hostname .+?)\s+(?=})", s).group(1))

# hostname triton.lakes.hostname.net
```

Comment: @Steve You only need to move the `hostname ` out of the group, like this `"(?<={)\s+hostname (.+?)\s+(?=})"`.

Comment: @Steve As you can see in the code, I added a `group(1)` at the end. Its function is to take the data matched by the group number 1. Please refer to the [document](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.Match.group) for detailed description.

Comment: @Steve It is correct, this result indicates that the match was successful, it is a `re.Match` object.